# squid ssl bump sslv3 enforce to allow old sites

Tags: ssl, proxy, squid, tls

Important: I have this question on stackoverflow but somebody told me this is more relevant place for this question. Thanks

I have configured squid(3.4.2) as ssl bumped proxy. I am setting proxy in firefox(29) to use squid for https/http.
Now it works for most sites, but some sites which support old SSL proto(sslv3) break, and I see squid not employing any workarounds for those like browsers do.

Sites which should work: https://usc-excel.officeapps.live.com/  , https://www.mahaconnect.in

As a workaround I have set sslproxy_version=3 , which enforces SSLv3 and above sites work.

My question: is there a better way to do this which does not involve enforcing SSLv3 for servers supporting TLS1 or better.

Now I know openssl doesn't automatically handle that. But I imagined squid would.

My squid conf snipper:

> http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB cert=/usr/local/squid/certs/SquidCA.pem
>
> always_direct allow all
>   ssl_bump server-first all
>   sslcrtd_program /usr/local/squid/libexec/ssl_crtd -s /usr/local/squid/var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB
>
> client_persistent_connections on
>   server_persistent_connections on
>
> sslproxy_version 3
>
> sslproxy_options ALL
>
> cache_dir aufs /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid 100 16 256
>
> coredump_dir /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid
>
> strip_query_terms off
>
> httpd_suppress_version_string on
>
> via off
>
> forwarded_for transparent
>
> vary_ignore_expire on
>
> refresh_pattern ^ftp:     1440    20% 10080
>   refresh_pattern ^gopher:  1440    0%  1440
>   refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0   0%  0
>   refresh_pattern .     0   20% 4320

UPDATE: I have tried compiling squid 3.4.5 with openssl 1.0.1h . No improvements

Comment: [SSLv3 Is Comprehensively Broken](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7568#page-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think squid implements any logic to automatically retry and SSL downgrade if the connection failed. So you have only the following options:

- Downgrade everything to SSLv3 like you propose. This is bad for security and will probably  cause other problems, when servers refuse to connect with SSLv3 for security reasons.
- Don't use servers which cannot deal with modern TLS. If they cannot even update their servers to recent TLS versions they have probably a lot more security problems.
- Make explicit exceptions for these servers, so that they don't get SSL bumped.

Comment: #2 - Squid would be acting as backbone proxy for the network so I have to provide support for as many sites as possible. One of the sites which doesnt work is Microsoft Office 365 ! :) . #3 - Can you please elaborate on exceptions that I can make. Thanks for you help

Comment: @Shrey: The office site should work, it works for me with TLSv1, e.g. no downgrade needed. The rest is SSLv3 only and will croak if you try better. Settings exceptions is done the usual squid way, see "Access Controls" in http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump

Comment: I cant find ACLs for the SSL error squid is throwing. I am getting error page with "Failed to establish a secure connection to 134.170.48.16 . The system returned: (104) Connection reset by peer (TLS code: SQUID_ERR_SSL_HANDSHAKE)" with https://usc-excel.officeapps.live.com/ with sslproxy_version 1 (above mentioned Squid conf). If your setup is working for this url, do you mind sending me your squid.conf.

Comment: @Shrey: There are no ACLs for exceptions, there are ACLs for hosts. So you have to find out which hosts cause problems, setup an acl "brokensites" and do "ssl_bump none brokensites" as described in the documentation. And I don't use squid myself, so I cannot send you the config. As for usc-excel.officeapps.live.com: it looks like there is a broken load balancer in front which cannot deal with larger client hellos (known problem with older F5). So it works with TLSv1 if you don't include all ciphers openssl has :(

Comment: We turned off SSLv3 on our web sites the very same day XP support ended, as that was the only reason to keep it. So far nobody has noticed. Cutting down the cipher list to work around Microsoft's broken F5 seems much more promising.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: F5 is not microsoft, but f5.com and I only assume that this is the case because it behaves like other broken F5 I've seen (the bug has fixed been by F5 long ago). And there is a workaround in openssl 1.0.1g (padding extension), which unfortunatly breaks IronPort :(

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your help. openssl s_client uses RC4-MD5 to connect to Ms officeapps .Adding RC4-MD5 to cipher list did the trick. Primary concern was https://usc-excel.officeapps.live.com/. I guess I will keep on changing cipher list to suit my needs. My final cipher list is EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH .

Answer (score 1):

Here is now my ssl-bump rules are setup and it works without a problem:

```
http_port 3128
http_port 3129 intercept
https_port 3130 intercept ssl-bump connection-auth=off generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=8MB cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem key=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.key cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/lib/squid_ssl_db -M 8MB
sslcrtd_children 50 startup=5 idle=1
```

This way you ignore the SSL/TLS situation and it is told to only use those ciphers (in progression down the list until It finds one it is compatible with, regardless of SSL/TLS in use). I loaded both websites you mentioned without a problem through my server.

Comment: Adding RC4-MD5 to cipher list makes  https://usc-excel.officeapps.live.com/ work

Answer (score -1):

If you change pFSense / Services / Squid Proxy Server / GEneral tab
Then check the SSL Man In The Middle Filtering 
area and change the 
SSL/MITM Mode 
from Splice WhiteList, Bumb OtherWise to the Splice ALL

the problem can be solve with a this shape.

OR

With a default value of the SSL/MITM Mode with Splice WhiteList, Bumb OtherWise 
you can goto ACLs atb and add desıred web site url to the WhiteList area ie: online.kktcmaliye.com